# Solve ld linker issues for building R source

Tags: r, linker, building

While trying to install R from source, I ran into linker issues, in particular: `undefined reference to 'u_getVersion_58`

I found limited information on this error (eg, [this post on the RStudio forum](https://community.rstudio.com/t/i-deleted-all-of-my-r-packages-and-libraries-in-a-lapse-of-judgement-and-now-i-am-in-a-limbo-where-i-cannot-either-fully-uninstall-or-fully-install-r-studio/14098)).
Despite running `apt-get build-dep`, these issues persisted.

It is apparent from [these comments by Dirk Eddenbuettel](https://r-sig-debian.r-project.narkive.com/TXtnZNg5/libr-so-error-to-install-r-3-5-0-in-ubuntu-18-04) that it relates to libicu versions. I have libicu version 60, while R 3.6.0 and similar recent versions seem to require version 58.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can install a previous version of `libicu` from source as follows:

```
wget https://github.com/unicode-org/icu/releases/download/release-58-3/icu4c-58_3-src.tgz
tar -xf icu4c-58_2-src.tgz
cd icu
make
make install
```

However, `make` is likely to run into a compilation error due to missing `xlocale.h`. As indicated [on this github post](https://github.com/Microsoft/AirSim/issues/751), this can be solved by running `ln -s /usr/include/locale.h /usr/include/xlocale.h`, as `xlocale.h` is just a subset of `locale.h` which was [removed from glibc recently](https://sourceware.org/glibc/wiki/Release/2.26#Removal_of_.27xlocale.h.27). After this, `make` and `make install` should succeed for icu version 58, and following that, for R.

Comment: Didn't work for me.  Still get same errors with make to R even though I enter LDFLAGS=-L/usr/local/lib where I installed icu 58

Comment: Actually I lied it worked after removing the 2 enable and 2 with parameters indicated here in configure https://docs.rstudio.com/resources/install-r-source/

Comment: As of 2023 August 31, I can't seem to decompress the .tgz as written. 
```
tar -xf icu4c-58_2-src.tgz


gzip: stdin: not in gzip format
tar: Child returned status 1
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

Comment: @ohnoplus try https://github.com/unicode-org/icu/releases/download/release-58-3/icu4c-58_3-src.tgz