# Error when compiling R 3.6.1 on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: r, ubuntu

I usually compile my own version of R, because I connect it to openmpi, and blas and a couple of other things.  This configure statement appears to work fine

```
./configure --enable-R-shlib --with-blas=-lopenblas --enable-memory-profiling
```

but then when I try to make I get this error

```
gcc -Wl,--export-dynamic -fopenmp  -L"../../lib" -L/usr/local/lib -o R.bin Rmain.o  -lR 
../../lib/libR.so: undefined reference to `ucol_strcollIter_58'
../../lib/libR.so: undefined reference to `u_getVersion_58'
```

which reading other threads appears to be related to the libicu-dev package?  It appears to be looking for version 58, but I checked and currently have ubuntu version libicu-dev (60.2-3ubuntu3) installed.  This might have something to do with a recent install of anaconda?

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libicu-dev is already the newest version (60.2-3ubuntu3).
libicu-dev set to manually installed.
```

Any suggestions how to get R to build against the newer installed version of libicu-dev?

Comment: It is helpful for you [libr .so error](https://r-sig-debian.r-project.narkive.com/TXtnZNg5/libr-so-error-to-install-r-3-5-0-in-ubuntu-18-04)

Comment: Thanks for this, did see it but not sure what it implies, other than removing anaconda?  Still looking for a solution.

Comment: I just installed v58 to build R, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55382028/solve-ld-linker-issues-for-building-r-source

Answer (score 0):

I successfully install R with this commander "./configure --prefix=/path/to/location LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/lib" . Where /usr/local/lib is the directory icu installed (wget https://github.com/unicode-org/icu/archive/release-58-3.tar.gz). I think it is the problem that anaconda/lib also contained libicuio.so.* files. After specifying certain LDFLAGS, it worked